# Trouble setting up ngx-lightbox in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Hey I am fairly new to angular and I'm building a website that is supposed to have lightbox galleries in each component. I was recommended ngx-lightbox to solve my photo gallery issue. I am having trouble getting it to work in the actual component.

In the documentation provided here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lightbox

I have completed the steps for importing ngx-lightbox into my project, I've declared it in my angular.json, I've imported it in appmodule.ts, I've added the html markup and the component code.

However the issue I am running into now is I'm getting the error,

"ERROR in src/app/pages/graphic-design/graphic-design.component.ts(11,19): error TS2314: Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s).
src/app/pages/graphic-design/graphic-design.component.ts(35,12): error TS2551: Property '_albums' does not exist on type 'GraphicDesignComponent'. Did you mean '_album'?
src/app/pages/graphic-design/graphic-design.component.ts(41,30): error TS2551: Property '_albums' does not exist on type 'GraphicDesignComponent'. Did you mean '_album'?"

this is my component code (which is directly copied from the documentation. Only thing I added was the two objects which are supposed to be images, but I cannot get past the errors to see if they work.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Lightbox } from 'ngx-lightbox';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graphic-design',
  templateUrl: './graphic-design.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graphic-design.component.css']
})
export class GraphicDesignComponent{
  private _album: Array = [
    { 
         src: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg",
         caption: "test",
         thumb: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg"

    },
    {
      src: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg",
      caption: "test",
      thumb: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg"
    }
  ];
  constructor(private _lightbox: Lightbox) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      const src = 'demo/img/image' + i + '.jpg';
      const caption = 'Image ' + i + ' caption here';
      const thumb = 'demo/img/image' + i + '-thumb.jpg';
      const album = {
         src: src,
         caption: caption,
         thumb: thumb
      };

      this._albums.push(album);
    }
  }

  open(index: number): void {
    // open lightbox
    this._lightbox.open(this._albums, index);
  }

  close(): void {
    // close lightbox programmatically
    this._lightbox.close();
  }
}
```

The markup code is literally the exact same from the documentation. I've listed my image file source inside the component code. Hoping I could get a clear explanation on what I need to fix inside my code in order to get this to work. I've never used ngx components before and I'm fairly new to angular.

Here is the markup code for reference:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of _albums; let i=index">
    <img [src]="image.thumb" (click)="open(i)"/>
  </div>
```

P.S. I've seen on some gallery components the small,medium,large file options. Do I need to do this for every image I upload to the gallery? I don't think ngx-lightbox has that but ngx-gallery did and I wasn't sure what that was all about. Anyways, really hoping I can get this setup soon. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized the Array as _album but using it as _albums so you just need to put "s" at the end of _album like that:

```
private _albums: Array = [
{ 
     src: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg",
     caption: "test",
     thumb: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg"

},
{
  src: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg",
  caption: "test",
  thumb: "../assets/images/Roycreates-red.jpg"
}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give type of Array (in other words- what will be type of elements contained by array).

Change this line:

```
 private _album: Array<{src: string, caption: string, thumb: string}> // ...rest of the code
```

Or you can use different syntax like:

```
private _album: {src: string, caption: string, thumb: string}[] = // ..rest of the code
```